# how to control score of Elasticsearch Fuzzines

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search, opensearch

I have a dataset of company names. each record contains the name of the company, and also some other values that can represent the name.
for example:
name: sam's club
other_names: sam's west

now the problem is that if i will look for a company called "blala west", that doesn't exists in the DB, I will get this record back with a high score.
I have to search for the "other_names" field as well, because I do want that "sam's west" will get back.

what is my best option to handle this?

the query we are using:

```
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "blabla west",
      "fields": [
        "company_name^2",
        "other_names^1"
      ],
      "fuzziness": "auto"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Could you please update your question with your current query which you are using ?

Comment: fixed, and another example just to clarify the problem:
I do have an "Amazon" record in the index, and I do want that "amazon services" will return Amazon as a result. so in some cases I do want that a 2-tokens search query that only 1 token exists will return a result and in others not

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query which will help you to boost document which are matching with the exact query values. Also, you can set `operator` value as `or` for getting result if any one term match.

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "blabla west",
            "fields": [
              "company_name^2",
              "other_names^1"
            ],
            "operator": "or",
            "fuzziness": "auto"
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "blabla west",
            "fields": [
              "company_name^2",
              "other_names^1"
            ],
            "operator": "or",
            "fuzziness": 0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```